# Syncfusion Schedule ServerAppointmentSaved never invoked

Tags: asp.net, webforms, syncfusion

I have snycfusion schedule component on my webforms application. I can get data from database with `ObjectDataSource` `SelectMethod`. Now I want to implement CRUD operations. I tried this on two different approaches.

1. Using `ObjectDataSource` and `InsertMethod` for create operation.
2. Using `Schedule` and `ServerAppointmentSaved` event

In both cases handlers was never invoked.

```
<ej:Schedule ID="Schedule"
    DataSourceID="ScheduleDataSource"
    Locale="sl-SI"
    CurrentView="Month"
    DateFormat="dd. MM. yyyy"
    TimeMode="Hour24"
    runat="server">
    <AppointmentSettings Id="Id"
        Subject="Name"
        StartTime="From"
        EndTime="To"
        Description="Description" />
</ej:Schedule>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ScheduleDataSource"
    SelectMethod="Get"
    runat="server" >  
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**And code behind:**

```
protected EventRepository EventRepository { get; set; } = new EventRepository();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScheduleDataSource.TypeName = EventRepository.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
    Schedule.ServerAppointmentSaved += Schedule_ServerAppointmentSaved;
}

private void Schedule_ServerAppointmentSaved(object sender, ScheduleEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Do I need javascript to invoke this events? Well what am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tried with the second method using the server-side events to perform CRUD operation. To invoke the server-side events, it should be first defined in your aspx page.

```
<ej:Schedule ID="Schedule1" ClientIDMode="Static" Height="525px" Width="100%" CurrentDate="10/10/2015" runat="server" DataSourceID="objectDataSource1" OnServerBeforeAppointmentCreate="Schedule1_ServerAppointmentSaved" OnServerBeforeAppointmentChange="Schedule1_ServerAppointmentEdited" OnServerBeforeAppointmentRemove="Schedule1_ServerAppointmentDeleted" OnServerDragStop="Schedule1_ServerDragStop" OnServerResizeStop="Schedule1_ServerResizeStop">
<appointmentsettings id="Id" subject="Subject" allday="AllDay" starttime="StartTime" endtime="EndTime" description="Description" recurrence="Recurrence" categorize="Categorize" />
</ej:Schedule>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objectDataSource1" runat="server" TypeName="ScheduleAppointmentsObjDatum" DataObjectTypeName="ScheduleAppointmentsObjData" SelectMethod="GetRecords">
```

You can also check this Knowledge base link for performing CRUD operation in Scheduler - 
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5159/how-to-perform-the-crud-operations-like-insert-update-and-delete-with-the-sql-database